# Disable officeclient.microsoft.com on Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

How do I disable the **officeclient.microsoft.com** on my laptop?

I am using Office 2016 on an HP Laptop with Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1.  Every time I open Outlook, Word, Excel or any other Office software, I get an annoying pop-up asking me to enter username and password credentials.

How do I disable these pop-ups?

Comment: What exactly are the messages you get?

Comment: There is a pop up asking me to enter username and password credentials

Comment: Anyone has any solution to my problem please help

Comment: Provide a screenshot, this may help identify the issue.